# Are there any disadvantages in experimental feature set to enable displacement?

Tags: displacement, experimental-features

Why is the "experimental feature set" (for enabling displacement) called experimental? Displacement is a pretty basic feature. It sounds like it comes with some disadvantages. Is it possible that something else does not work or is broken if I build my scene with it?

Comment: "*Displacement is a pretty basic feature.*" Putting a feature behind an experimental flag depends on how stable or well tested it has been by developers, not on how basic its functionality is or how useful the feature is as perceived by end users.

Comment: ok and what's unstable about it? and what for example can be broken in the future? is my computer more likely to crash or is the file more likely to have some bugs or something?

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/features.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Displacement works just fine within the supported feature set.
You only need to go "experimental" to enable *adaptive subdivision*.

Regarding disadvantages of the experimental set:
*"Use experimental or incomplete features that may be broken or change in the future"*

[image]